# CGAL versus VTK

Tags: vtk, cgal

What is the difference between the CGAL and the VTK libraries? Both incorporate a lot of the standard geometric algorithms. Can anyone list some application domains where the one is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VTK is mostly targeted toward visualization (frontend). It includes some computational geometry functions out of convenience (e.g. Delaunay triangulation). It would be better suited for viewing MRI scans, visualizing large data sets, or converting point clouds / meshes from one format to another for example.

CGAL is targeted toward computational geometry (backend). It will require some type of frontend (e.g. OpenGL, VTK) to view the result. It would be better suited for molecular biology, astronomy, architectural design backends for example.

Answer (score 1):

Among other differences license should be mentioned. VTK is licensed under BSD and could be used in commercial products for free. While CGAL is dual licensed under GPLv3 (most of it) and commercial license. And to use it in commercial products you should purchase commercial license or publish your sources under GPLv3 (unlikely way for commercial products).

Answer (score 0):

VTK is good for scientific visualization (plotting values onto a mesh with a given colour scale), and all that goes with it (axes, filters and so on), it has quite a few tools for mesh processing and other things which [paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) gives a front end to, if you want to experiment. It's no good for textures, dynamic meshes, particles and all manner of other game/VR related technologies.